# psuhing an object inside another object

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object of objects which should be something like this.

```
let data={
 { _id:10010,
   value:"tom"
},
{
_id:2002,
 value:22882
}
}
```

One solution that i could think of was this .

```js
let data = {};

data.content = ({
  _id: 1001,
  value: "tom"
});
data.content = ({
  id: 10001,
  status: "harry"
});

console.log(data);
```

However if we do this we can only have one content inside our main object .Can we accomplish the desired data format while creating an object of objects ?

Comment: Because the goal is invalid JS. Properties of an object need a name, most likely you need an array here.

Comment: It's unclear what is the input and the expected output. Can you please clarify those? Besides, your second piece of code is not valid js.

Comment: you could take an array for more than one object. or you need an object with individual keys for the nested objects.

Comment: Make `data` an array `[]` and then simply `data.push({...})`…?!

Comment: Object are collection of `property: value` pairs. You had provided the values, but where are properties?

Comment: @rv7 "key" is the keyword here.

Comment: @Teemu actually the comment was for the OP, i know that arrays are `key: value` pairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.

```
let data=[
  { _id:10010,
    value:"tom"
  },
  { _id:2002,
    value:22882
  }
]
data.push({
  _id:1001,
  value:"tom"
});
data.push({
  _id:1001,
  value:"tom"
});
```

Push method will add object to the array. If you need something else you can create more complex function/class that handles the requirements, but this maybe would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to do with array

```js
let data=[];
data.push({
  _id:1001,
  value:"tom"
});
data.push({
  id:10001,
  status:"harry"
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an "object of objects". Objects store data in `key:value` pairs. You might consider creating an **array** of objects, after which you can reference the array items using indexes:

```js
let data = [];

data.push({
  _id: 10010,
  value: "tom"
});

data.push({
  _id: 2002,
  value: 22882
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of arrays in order to achieve the result.

```
let data = [];
data[0]= {
    _id:10010,
    value:"tom"
}
data[1]= {
    _id:2002,
    value:22882
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you really mean is

```
let data={
  10010: { _id:10010,
    value:"tom"
  },
  2002: {
    _id:2002,
    value:22882
  }
}
```

Property of objects has to be key value pair, meaning in order to have a object nested in an object, as a value, u need to pair it with a key. Hence using the id of object as the key to store it.

```
data['10010'] = { _id: 10010, value: 'tom' };
data['2002'] = { _id: 2002, value: 22882 };
```